# SELECT and UPDATE in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to perform a query and I have no idea to make it work without using stored procedures, but due to limitations of the programming language I'm using, its mysql platform won't accept stored procedures/functions.

The code is:

```
select
    (myrpg_faction_info.funds) as bank,
    (
        myrpg_faction_info.paycheckrate +
        myrpg_faction_ranks.paycheckrate +
        sum(myrpg_faction_flags.paycheckrate)
    ) as rate

from 
    myrpg_faction_info
inner join
    myrpg_faction_ranks 
        on 
            myrpg_faction_info.id = myrpg_faction_ranks.fid and 
            myrpg_faction_ranks.rank=1
inner join
    myrpg_faction_flags 
        on 
            myrpg_faction_info.id=myrpg_faction_flags.fid and
            (1 << myrpg_faction_flags.flag) & 1
where myrpg_faction_info.id=1
```

But I have to save the rate and bank variables (in SQL) and update the faction_info table to take off the rate from the faction_info.bank column and select the value taken off, but I have no idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
update mfi
set myrpg_faction_info.funds -
    (
        myrpg_faction_info.paycheckrate +
        myrpg_faction_ranks.paycheckrate +
        sum(myrpg_faction_flags.paycheckrate)
    ) as rate
from 
    myrpg_faction_info mfi
inner join
    myrpg_faction_ranks 
        on 
            myrpg_faction_info.id = myrpg_faction_ranks.fid and 
            myrpg_faction_ranks.rank=1
inner join
    myrpg_faction_flags 
        on 
            myrpg_faction_info.id=myrpg_faction_flags.fid and
            (1 << myrpg_faction_flags.flag) & 1
where myrpg_faction_info.id=1
```